# How to get XMLType column from Oracle database using rs.getSQLXML() fuction from java.sql package?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sqlxml

When I try to get XMLType column from Oracle database I get an error:

`java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type`

The problem is in `rs.getSQLXML(1)` function.

My code:

```java
Connection conn = null;
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
String user="user";
String pw = "pww";

try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,user,pw);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

Statement stmt = null;
String query = "select e.doc from XMLTABLE e";
try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        SQLXML sqlxml = rs.getSQLXML(1);
        String xml1= sqlxml.getString();


        System.out.println(xml1);
    }
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}
```

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTABLE (
    id NUMBER(4),
    doc XMLTYPE
);
```

I know that there are other ways to get XMLType column like `rs.getOPAQUE(1)` or `rs.getCLOB(1)` with modified query. But I need to use **rs.getSQLXML(1)** function.

I use ojdbc6 version.

EDIT :

I tried with ojdbc8 and debugged ojdbc8 code and there is something like this:

```
            OPAQUE var2 = (OPAQUE)this.getOracleObject(var1);
            return var2 == null ? null : (SQLXML)var2;
        } catch (ClassCastException var3) {
            throw (SQLException)((SQLException)DatabaseError.createSqlException(this.getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 4).fillInStackTrace());
        }
```

and it returns `java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xdb.XMLType cannot be cast to java.sql.SQLXML` . This may be a probelm here. **What can i do with this ?**

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a newer version of the Oracle JDBC driver? ojdbc is **not** a version: ojdbc6 means it is for Java 6, and versions of the ojdbc6 drivers are pretty old by now.

Comment: I tried with **ojdbc7** and newest **ojdbc8** and i get this same error. Maybe rs.getSQLXML() function is not compatible with Oracle XMLType or maybe i need to do some extra change in sql query ?

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver itself does not provide everything needed to use the JDBC XML API.

You need additional libraries together with base driver jar: `xdb.jar` and and `xmlparserv.jar`.

`xdb.jar` can be downloaded from the same place [as the base driver](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/download-3320542.html)

The `xmlparserv.jar` should be [somewhere in your Oracle installation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_gs.htm#ADXDK19067).

Comment: I already have `xdb.jar` and `xmlparserv2.jar` in my project.

Comment: @wolukasz: do you have the apache POI libraries in your classpath as well? I remember, there was some problem if both were used at the same time